# how to add the object to JS as a slot, when get the signal that page was cleared?

Tags: javascript, qt, signals, slot

> ```
> #include <QApplication>  
> #include "QWebFrame"  
> #include "QWebView"  
> #include "directory.h"  
> #include "QObject"  
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])  {  
>     QApplication app(argc, argv);  
>     Directory dir;  
>     QWebView webview;  
>
>    webview.load(QUrl("/home/dailu/Desktop/Project2.3/Surface.html"));  
>
>    webview.page()->mainFrame()->addToJavaScriptWindowObject("dir",&dir);  
>
>    QObject::connect( webview.page()->mainFrame(),  
>
>                    SIGNAL(javaScriptWindowObjectCleared()),  
>
>                    webview.page()->mainFrame(),  
>
>                    SLOT(aaddToJavaScriptWindowObject("dir",&dir)));  
>
>    webview.show();  
>    return app.exec();
> ```
>
> }

It's not working~~I just want to catch the signal that page is cleared and then >send the   object again to make sure the data can be reload in page..I'm a fresh of Qt Language....So.could u give a demo to understand or just fix it..thx!